# Set variables based on path without using directory-local variables

Tags: hooks, local-variables, path, compilation-mode

I want to set variables, in particular, `compile-command` and tabbing related variables based on the path of the file I'm editing.

In my `.vimrc` I use the following to do this.

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */path/*.ext set tabbing-setting
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */path/*.ext set makeprg=build.sh
```

These cause vim to run the `set ...` commands whenever I create or read a file that matches the pattern `*/path/*.ext`.

I don't want to use directory-local variables because I want this to live with the rest of my emacs configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directory-local variables were actually designed for this use case as well.  Read [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html), especially at the end, where it discusses `dir-locals-set-directory-class`.  The idea here is that you can keep the directory-local settings somewhere other than in the `.dir-locals.el` file.

Another way to accomplish this same thing is to make settings directory-dependent in the relevant mode hooks.  For example, something like:

```
(defun my-set-c-style ()
  (if (buffer-file-name)
      (cond
       ((string-match "/some/random/path" (buffer-file-name))
        (c-set-style "BSD")
        (make-local-variable 'c-basic-offset)
        (setq c-basic-offset 4)))
... you get the idea
```

This function would be attached to `c-mode-hook`.

The advantage of the directory-local approach is that you can keep all the settings related to a project in one spot.  The advantage of the second approach is that it can also be used for things that you can't do via directory-locals, for example binding a key.

Comment: What if I want to specify the directory with wildcards? Can a directory class be made to work with that? Or should I use the hook strategy?

Comment: There isn't a built-in way to make the directory class approach work with wildcards, so yeah, you'd have to use hooks.  If it's a small list of directories, though, you can just list them all.